# `eval` works on Ubuntu but doesn't work on Debian and Kali

Tags: bash, debian, shell-script

I've some scripts created on Ubuntu. When I use them on Kali and Debian, 
I found that the `eval` command that I use extract the data from formatted text files doesn't work well. Anyone knows how to get it working on those Debian-based systems?

### How I used `eval` (small example)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
basename=$(basename $0)
dirname=$(dirname $0)
if [[ $EUID -gt 0 ]];
then
    exec sudo "$dirname/$basename" "$@"
fi
myscript=$dirname/$basename
function getlistof () {
    awk "/^#BEGIN-$1#/, /^#END-$1#/" $myscript | grep -v '#BEGIN\|#END' | grep "$2"
}
getlistof log mylink | while read mylink # here mylink='mylink=(source=... destn=....) (var)'
    do
        eval "$mylink" # and here should become mylink='(source=... destn=....)(array)'
        eval "${mylink[*]}" # and here the script should know about vars inside the array!
        echo " $source $destn"
    done
exit
#BEGIN-log#
mylink=(source=sources_one destn=destn_one)
mylink=(source=source_two destn=destn_two)
#END-log#
```

### Here's the output of this script on ubuntu

```sh
 younes@unix:~$ ./myscript
 sources_one destn_one
 source_two destn_two
```

**News**

and while i'm trying to simplify the question i got it working on *kali-linux* trough chroot env!

```sh
younes@unix:~$ lsb_release -srci
Ubuntu
15.04
vivid
younes@unix:~$ ./myscript
 sources_one destn_one
 source_two destn_two
younes@unix:~$ sudo cp -f myscript /.Kali-2.0-sana/home/younes/
younes@unix:~$ chroothere /.Kali-2.0-sana
root@unix:/# lsb_release -srci
Kali
2.0
sana
root@unix:/# /home/younes/myscript 
 sources_one destn_one
 source_two destn_two
root@unix:/#
```

thans editor teachers helpers , for every byte you wrote here !

Comment: _"i found that the eval command not working well"_  You need to show us the `eval` command that you are using and exactly how it behaves differently on the different systems.

Comment: 1) Don't capitalize variables unless you export them or unless they're bash config vars. 2) Quote variables; always, unless you need $IFS splitting.

Comment: (1) You still haven't said how the commands behave differently on the different systems.  (2) There is not even enough information to try run that script. please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (3) In shell scripting, it is very rare that `eval` is the right tool to use.  That appears true here.  If you could change the format of `file.txt`, you could eliminate `eval` and simplify this script.

Comment: on ubuntu tested with and without .extension (nothing related to .txt) ,  on debian i don't get vars or arrays values (empty) !

Comment: I think I understand why it failed, but can't figure out why it worked.

Comment: The _small example_ works for me as expected on Debian 8, with `bash` version "GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"

Comment: yes it's working , the only conflict wase there is : on UBUNTU can work either " echo $var-or-arry | eval " or "eval $var-or-array"           but on DEBIAN-based-systems works only "eval $var-or-array"  the 'echo $var-or-array | eval' doesn't work

Comment: Your edit to change it to `eval ${mklink[*]}` actually made it work, rendering the whole question useless. By the way, the `| eval` way doesn't work on my ubuntu.

Comment: Ub 15.04 (bash, ksh, zsh, dash, everything I can think of).

Comment: Polished version: https://gist.github.com/Arthur2e5/5694c113912a43fbdef1

Comment: thanks man , you did that for me :3  i've a lot to discover there :)    by the way i've a nice anon guy on my fb friends-list which called Arthur ! you may be the same person :D or at laest the same personality , being supportive and giving help ... thank you so much brother !

Comment: Unfortunately I seldom use FB, and on FB my name is the legal name which you may see on my about.me page :/

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT

The user has extensivelly changed his question, this answer was an edit of the code the user posted which exist no more in his question now.

There is new code and the question has changed to something else.

As such, this answer should be regarded as old (and invalid) code.

## Original

If I am understanding your code correctly.
You are using eval just to get the value of two vars inside your code.
That is seen as "bad practice".

If you change your source file from:

```
LINK=(SRC=/.hd/home/younes/.conky DST=/home/younes/.conky)
```

to

```
/.hd/home/younes/.conky /home/younes/.conky
```

or even if you insert the pair of values in a here document, this code will do the same thing without eval:

```
while read SRC DST
do
    [[ ! -e $SRC ]] && [[ ! -e $DST ]] && echo "oOpsS! $DST" && exit
    [[ ! -e $SRC ]] &&  mv "$DST" "$SRC"
    [[ ! -e $DST ]] &&  $LINKIT "$SRC" "$DST"
    ls -l "$DST" | grep "$SRC" &>/dev/null || $LINKIT "$SRC" "$DST"
done <<\_list_of_dir_pairs_
/.hd/home/younes/.conky             /home/younes/.conky
/.hd/home/younes/.fonts             /home/younes/.fonts
/.hd/home/younes/.thumbnails        /home/younes/.thumbnails
/.hd/home/younes/.xbindkeys         /home/younes/.xbindkeys
/.hd/home/younes/.xbindkeys_config  /home/younes/.xbindkeys_config
/.hd/home/younes/.xbindkeysrc       /home/younes/.xbindkeysrc
_list_of_dir_pairs_
```

And, if you do need the array LINK, do:

```
LINK=($SCR $DST)
```

Note that I have quoted the var expansions of SRC and DST in mv and LINKIT, and changed LINKIT to $LINKIT (I am assuming that is a variable, and not a function. Change back if you need).

Comment: i like this as new knowlege for me , thank you !

Comment: As this answer no longer works for the question (the question has been edited and converted to something else), vote this comment if you want this answer erased. Thanks.

Comment: i don't know much about this site rules , and that why i decided to not answer anything here !      and i edited it cause it was unclear ! anyhow i don't want your answer to be removed , i appreciate it  , and it's usefull ,  let other people see it !  and thank you :)

Comment: Let people VOTE as they whish. If I am correct, probably, this answer will no be erased.

Comment: As for your edits, it is assumed that a question has been though before being asked and will remain reasonably static for others to answer. If the question changes too much, the answers will have no relation to the question. That just confuses people, and is not helpful to anyone. If the answers received do not address the problem you need solving: **Ask Again**. Make the new question better, and wait for help.